# How to convert Cartesian coordinates epitrochoid graph into polar coordinates in pascalABC?

Tags: math, geometry, pascal, polar-coordinates, cartesian-coordinates

For my student project I need to create pascalABC.NET program that makes Epitrochoid graph in Cartesian and Polar coordinate systems. I made some simple code for Cartesian system and it seems to work pretty well, how can i convert it to polar system now? Is there any math equations for epitrochoid in polar system that i can use for this program? Hope someone can help me :)

Code i made for Cartesian system:

```
uses graphABC;
var c,x,y:integer;
r1,r2,m,h,t,ms:real;
begin
setwindowsize(500,500);
centerwindow;
c:=250;
r1:=1;
r2:=0.2;
m:=r2/r1;//m=0.2
h:=0.3;
ms:=(c-50)/(r1+2*r2);
setpenwidth(2);
setpencolor(clGreen);
circle(c,c,round(r1*ms));
setpencolor(clRed);
t:=0;
while t<=360 do
 begin
  x:=c+round((r1*(m+1)*cos(m*t)-h*cos((m+1)*t))*ms);
  y:=c-round((r1*(m+1)*sin(m*t)-h*sin((m+1)*t))*ms);
  if t=0 then moveto(x,y) else lineto(x,y);
  t:=t+0.1;
 end;
end.
```

[image: Thats how graph looks in Cartesian system]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot build explicit function `ro(theta)` for epitrochoid.

It is possible to make `ro(t)` and `theta(t)` for `t` parameter:

```
ro = sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
theta = arctan2(y, x)
```

where `x, y` are expressions like your `r1*(m+1)*cos(m*t)-h*cos((m+1)*t))*ms`

[Example of formula derivation for epicycloid](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Epicycloid.html)
and result for [epitrochoid](https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/epitrochoid/epitrochoid.shtml)

Seems a bit unnatural, in my mind...

Problems - it is hard to get equal-spaced points by `theta`, also note that one `theta` value might correspond to two `ro` values (loops at your picture).